# Having to define pure virtual in mutli-level inheritance

Tags: c++, oop

I have a mutli-level class hierarchy with an abstract base class at the top level. It doesn't make sense to implement the pure virtual at the mid-level of the hierarchy but without it, the compile fails.
Please see the following example and embedded code comments.

I get errors like "undefined reference to vtable" or "cannot allocate because functions are pure", depending on which lines are included.
The only way it works is if I implement the method setValue in D1, even though it's not applicable there.

I've found somewhat similar posts but haven't found any which answer this specific case. As you can probably tell, I'm new to C++/OOP.

Thanks for having a look.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

//  abstract base class
class AB { 
public:
    virtual void setName(std::string s) = 0;

    // Doesn't compile if I don't have this:
    // Different error if pure or non-pure
    virtual void setValue(int value) = 0;
};

class D1 : public AB {
public:

  // Doesn't compile if I don't have this line, but it's
  // not applicable to D1.
  //
  //void setValue(int value) { }

    void setName(std::string s) {
      std::cout << "D1::setName to " << s << std::endl;
      name_ = s;
    }
private:
  std::string name_;
};

class D2 : public D1 { 

public:
  void setValue(int value) {
      std::cout << "D2::setValue to " << value << std::endl;
      val_ = value;
    }

private:
  int val_;
};

int main() {

    AB* pD1= new D1;
    AB* pD2= new D2;

    pD1->setName("a D1");

    pD2->setName("a D2");
    pD2->setValue(5);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: To be a concrete class, child class has to implement all of the pure virtual functions which it is inheriting, otherwise the child class will also become abstract, and you can't instantiate an abstract class.

Comment: My bad on trying to instantiated AB. So is it highlighting a flawed class design that I'm forced to provide setValue in D1?

Comment: Even if you weren't forced to provide the definition of `setValue` in `D1`, it doesn't make any difference in the class design, because _if just using `D1` with polymorphism_, eventually you'll get a declaration of `setValue` from `AB` either if you don't want it in `D1`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide an implementation of all the virtual pure methods that are likely to appear at the level of a concrete class -- for which a constructor is called with a `new` or with a variable definition --.

This is the case if you don't provide the `void setValue(int value) { }` at the `D1`'s level and the error is

> "cannot allocate because functions are pure"

If you don't want to provide `D1::setValue`, you should give a default
implementation for virtual `void AB::setValue(int value) {}`. The error

> "undefined reference to vtable"

comes from the missing implementation. You have declared `void AB::setValue(int value);`, but have not provided any implementation for it. As it is a virtual method, the linker complains with this message.

Answer (score 0):

```
AB* pD1= new D1;
```

constructs a D1. In order for D1 to be constructable it must implement everything its base classes left pure.

```
virtual void setName(std::string s) = 0; // implemented by D1
virtual void setValue(int value) = 0; // not implemented by D1
```

D1 does not implement `setValue`, this is not complete.

Solution: If you want to have instances of `D1` and for users of `AB` to be able to use `setValue`, implement `setValue`. There is no other alternative. If users of `AB` will never use `setValue` then remove it from `AB`. Don't abstract or expose what you aren't going to use.

Off topic recommendation:

Implement the destructors even if they do nothing. A default destructor is not virtual and this will cause problems making sure the correct subobject is destroyed rather than the base class.